# img tag not working in wordpress post

Tags: image, wordpress

If you follow [this](http://deangrobler.com/?page_id=119) link to one of the pages on my site and you scroll to the bottom you'll see that there's supposed to be 2 images in the bottom of the post. For some reason they're not displaying?

If you view source and then copy and paste the URL of the images directly in your browser it loads fine. Is there something I'm missing here? Must be wordpress related though I'm sure..

Thanks for any replies!

PS - I'm still working on that page, I know it looks a bit crappy at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about the Adobe icons? You need to prefix their URLs with http:// so they are fully-qualified.

Comment: yep those are the ones. I've tried that but for some reason when I let the page go live they kinda just disappear? And it revers back to 'www.etcetc....'

Comment: Try it without adding your domain then. Just do `/images/adobeDocumentIcon.png`.